# How can I get a MySqlConnection object from a DLL

Tags: c#, mysql, dll

My goal is to create a DLL that can be used with several different programs that will return the MySqlConnection object. That way if the credentials ever change, it will only need to be modified in one place.

Right now I can get my MySqlConnection object successfully from another C# file included in the project, but when I try to retrieve it from my DLL instead I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Connection must be valid
>   and open.

Can anyone spot the error in my code or my logic? Is there a better way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

**My DLL code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

//For MySql connections
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace LinMySqlConnections
{
    public class MySqlMain
    {
       public static MySqlConnection OpenConnection()
       {
         string server = "database.address";
         string database = "databaseName";
         string user = "dbUser";
         string pass = "dbPass";

         string connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + 
                                    user + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + pass + ";";

         MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

         return connection;
    }
}
```

**My Main code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using LinMySqlConnections;

namespace ODSTesting
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      MySqlConnection mainDB = LinMySqlConnections.MySqlMain.OpenConnection();

      if (mainDB != null)
      {
        string query1 = "SELECT * FROM table";

          MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query1, mainDB);
          MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        else
          Console.WriteLine("mainDB was null dude");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The connection is not open 
    connection.Open();

Comment: start by reading the error message.. it's telling you that you do not have an open connection.. `cmd.Connection.Open();` use google next time

Comment: @AndreyBelykh, thanks! I had the .Open() in my included file, but overlooked that when moving it to the DLL. That solved the issue - if you post it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Is this dll only to provide a way to change a single thing in the case the connection string ever changes? If so, why not just simply store it (or even better, its components) in a file somewhere so that programs simply read it from there? You don't even have to recompile anything that way.

Comment: Yes that is the primary purpose. Not having to recompile would be more convenient, but aren't the credentials a little more secure if they are in a compiled DLL versus a plain text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection is not open

```
connection.Open();
```